# How can one see the SQL statements that jOOQ executes?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I use jOOQ to query/insert/update data from/into a table.

Is there a way to see the SQL statements that JOOQ executes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we profile JOOQ statements for speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561317/how-can-we-profile-jooq-statements-for-speed)

Answer (score 32):

Look for your log configuration file (or create one) and set the log level of the class `org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener` as `debug` or `trace`, e.g. into `log4j.properties`.

In spring you can set the log level DEBUG into your application.properties this way

```
logging.level.org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener=DEBUG
```

For the following query

```
create.select(BOOK.ID, BOOK.TITLE).from(BOOK).orderBy(BOOK.ID).limit(1, 2).fetch();
```

you should get a log like

```
Executing query          : select "BOOK"."ID", "BOOK"."TITLE" from "BOOK" order by "BOOK"."ID" asc limit ? offset ?
-> with bind values      : select "BOOK"."ID", "BOOK"."TITLE" from "BOOK" order by "BOOK"."ID" asc limit 2 offset 1
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a blog article on the jOOQ blog describing how to debug-log the generated SQL:

https://blog.jooq.org/debug-logging-sql-with-jooq/

Note, this was also dealt with on this Stack Overflow question here:

[How can we profile JOOQ statements for speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561317/how-can-we-profile-jooq-statements-for-speed)